# How can I add a smooth fade in/out transition to AVPlayerLooper?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have an `AVPlayerLooper` which uses an `AVQueuePlayer`. It's really easy to loop the video, but I wanted to fade in the video during the first second, and fade out during the last second. I've been able to make it fade in and out by using an `AVPlayerLayer` and a `CABasicAnimation` which animates the opacity appropriately, but I can't make it seamless and 100% reliable. I've tried using `NotificationCenter` for the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` and `AVPlayerItemTimeJumped`. I've also tried using KVO with the key `isReadyForDisplay`. When I tried to `addPeriodicTimeObserver`, I can't get it accurate enough to correctly time the fades. I've even tried to `addBoundaryTimeObserver`, but that wasn't consistent enough either.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how to implement a crossfade into an AVPlayerLooper/AVQueuePlayer?

Answer (score 0):

`AVPlayerLooper` has always struck me as a strange class - wouldn't looping have been more orthogonal and useful as a wrapped `AVAssetTrack` or even an `AVPlayerItem`? e.g.

```
loop(AVAssetTrack) -> AVAssetTrack
loop(AVPlayerItem) -> AVPlayerItem
```

Anyway, you could create your initial fade in as a `AVMutableComposition` and queue it up, then queue up the `AVPlayerLooper` looping version that you've already done.

As for fade out, you can queue up a fade-out, which will play once you  stop the looping with `looper.disableLooping()`. (actually, maybe this answers my question, having `disableLooping` on an `AVAssetTrack` or `AVPlayerItem` would be weird).